# JSONObject and Streams/Lambda

Tags: json, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to get more familiar with Java lambda, can do some streams and such but still a lot to learn.

Got this simple code using JSONObject and JSONArray (org.json.simple with this exact library and no other because Gson is too easy :P) is there a way to simplify the code with java lambda/streams? (I tried with no luck)

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("someData");

    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();

    double total = 0;
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject iteratedJson = iterator.next();
        // iteratedJson.get("ip") = "101.99.99.101" example values
        String ip = (String) iteratedJson.get("ip");
        // Need only first octet
        ip = ip.substring(0, ip.indexOf("."));

        if (Integer.valueOf(ip) >= 1 && Integer.valueOf(ip) <= 100) {
            // Another object inside the array object
            JSONObject locationObject = (JSONObject) iteratedJson.get("location");
            // Id is int but JSONObject don't let me parse int...
            long locationId = (Long) locationObject.get("id");

            if (locationId == 8) {
                // iteratedJson.get("amount") = "$1,999.10" example values
                Number number = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse((String)iteratedJson.get("amount"));

                // Don't need a lot of precission
                total = total + number.doubleValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say *"(I tried with no luck)"*. You must share the attempt while asking for relevant help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

first of all to extract data from JsonObject I've created a class. this class takes a JosonObject as an argument and extract its values as bellow.

```
class ExtractData {
  Integer ip;
  long id;
  double amount;

  public ExtractData(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    this.ip = Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.get("ip").toString().split("\\.")[0]);
    this.id = Long.parseLong(((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("location")).get("id").toString());
    try {
         this.amount = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)
                            .parse((String) jsonObject.get("amount")).doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
           this.amount = 0d;
    }
  }

   // getter&setter
}
```

then you can use stream API to calculate the sum of the amount property.

```
jsonArray.stream()
         .map(obj -> new ExtractData((JSONObject) obj))
         .filter(predicate)
         .mapToDouble(value -> ((ExtractData) value).getAmount())
         .sum();
```

for simplifying I've extracted filter operation.

```
Predicate<ExtractData> predicate = extractData -> 
           extractData.getIp()>=1 && extractData.getIp()<=100 && extractData.getId() == 8;
```

Comment: Totally perfect. Please let me know if I'm correct; 1.- on .map it's created an ExtractData out of JSONObject (which has ip, id and amount). 2.- on .filter it's filtered the values needed from ExtractData. 3.- on .mapToDouble it's taking out the amount from ExtractData and finally 4.- .sum does what it says. Is that right? I didn't know you can create a new object from the object streamed/mapped and then do more things with that new created object.